# Rails query which aggregates (with an array or jsonb hash) the count of ordered products by the color of each product

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, aggregate-functions

In my Rails (v6.0) app, I have a `Product` model listing the `name` and the color (*actually `flavors['color']`, because products variants as color are stored in a jsonb field named `flavors`*) of each product, and an associated `Order` model which has and belongs to many (HABTM) products (*actually it's a HMT relation with a join table listing the quantity of products per order, but let's ignore this by now*).

I can count the number of ordered products grouped by product's color with this query

```
Order.joins(:products).group(:name,"products.flavors ->> 'color'").order(:name,'products_flavors_color').count
```

which outputs

```
=> {["jacket", "black"]=>59, ["jacket", "orange"]=>34, ["jacket", "white"]=>9, ["jacket", "red"]=>1, ["sockets", "black"]=>76, ["sockets", "green"]=>6, ["gloves", "black"]=>94, ["gloves", "green"]=>9, ["shirt", "black"]=>120, ["shirt", "orange"]=>62, ["shirt", "white"]=>19, ["shirt", "red"]=>3, ["pants", "black"]=>129, ["pants", "orange"]=>63, ["pants", "white"]=>18, ["pants", "red"]=>3, ["hat", "black"]=>86, ["hat", "orange"]=>45, ["hat", "white"]=>13, ["hat", "red"]=>1}
```

I would like to be able to aggregate (with an array or jsonb hash) the count of ordered products by color of each product, to have an object like this:

```
{"jacket"=>{"black":59,"orange":34,"white":9,"red":1},"sockets"=>{"black":76,"green":6},"gloves"=>{"black":94,"green":9},"shirt"=>{"black":10,"orange":62,"white":19,"red":3},"pants"=>{"black":129,"orange":63,"white":18,"red":3},"hat"=>{"black":86,"orange":45,"white":13,"red":1}}
```

Rather than manipulating the object in Rails (unless it can be done with a very efficient method), I would prefer if it's done by the RDBMS (PostgreSQL 12.4) using an aggregate function such as `array_agg()` or `jsonb_agg()`.

I've tried something like this

```
Order.joins(:products).select(:name,"ARRAY_AGG(products.flavors ->> 'color')").group(:name).count(:name)
```

but it loses the aggregate function. Since it looks more like a PostgreSQL question, so pure SQL hints are accepted as well, but I would like to be able to implement the query with agnostic Active Record query methods (except the aggregate function, but avoiding `find_by_sql` or arel-like).

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to be able to natively get the resulting object you want from a SQL query simply because you cannot nest grouping like that; however, what you can do is manipulate the resulting `Hash` into the `Hash` structure that you want.

For Example

```
result = Order.joins(:products)
              .group(:name,"products.flavors ->> 'color'")
              .order(:name,'products_flavors_color')
              .count
#=> {["jacket", "black"]=>59, ["jacket", "orange"]=>34, ["jacket", "white"]=>9, ["jacket", "red"]=>1, ["sockets", "black"]=>76, ["sockets", "green"]=>6, ["gloves", "black"]=>94, ["gloves", "green"]=>9, ["shirt", "black"]=>120, ["shirt", "orange"]=>62, ["shirt", "white"]=>19, ["shirt", "red"]=>3, ["pants", "black"]=>129, ["pants", "orange"]=>63, ["pants", "white"]=>18, ["pants", "red"]=>3, ["hat", "black"]=>86, ["hat", "orange"]=>45, ["hat", "white"]=>13, ["hat", "red"]=>1}

desired_result = result.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = {}}) do |((article,color),count),obj|
                    obj[article][color] = count
                 end
#=> {"jacket"=>{"black"=>59, "orange"=>34, "white"=>9, "red"=>1}, 
# "sockets"=>{"black"=>76, "green"=>6}, 
# "gloves"=>{"black"=>94, "green"=>9}, 
# "shirt"=>{"black"=>120, "orange"=>62, "white"=>19, "red"=>3}, 
# "pants"=>{"black"=>129, "orange"=>63, "white"=>18, "red"=>3}, 
# "hat"=>{"black"=>86, "orange"=>45, "white"=>13, "red"=>1}}
```